# How do I select elements of an np.array with multipleconditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to add a column with information about the amount of advertising channel bans. Read some solutions, but they didn't help.

For one entry my approach works:

```
mask = df['advban'] == 'email'
df.loc[mask, 'anz_advban'] = 1
```

But if I try multiple conditions, it leeds to an error

```
mask = df['advban'] == 'email, letter' or df['advban'] == 'call, sms' or df['advban'] == 'email, catalog' or df['advban'] == 'letter, catalog'
df.loc[mask, 'anz_advban'] = 2
```

Comment: Use the `|` (OR) operator: `(df['advban'] == 'email, letter') | (df['advban'] == 'call, sms') | (df['advban'] == 'email, catalog') | (df['advban'] == 'letter, catalog')`

Comment: also, it's not clear, but if your checking that a value exists in a list of values, don't use `==`, use `df['advban'].isin(['email', 'letter'])` instead